# How to collision detect objects with vx and vy?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been trying to find out how to block the player from moving the correct way. However, the way I've been doing now, stops the player from moving at all.
I want the player to stop moving horizontally if it touches the side of the block's collisionArea, and if it touches the top or bottom of the block's collisionArea, I want it to stop moving vertically only. So that way you can still move up and down when you touch the side, and side to side when you touch top or botttom. Thanks.

```
if (player.collisionArea.hitTestObject(block.collisionArea))
{
    player.y -= vy;
    player.x -= vx;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic approach is to move your object, test if the current position hits your obstacle, then move it back if it does. This could be adapted to separate out the x and y axis quite easily (reduced code for clarity):

```
player.x += vx;
if(player.hitTestObject(block)){
    player.x -= vx;
}

player.y += vy;
if(player.hitTestObject(block)){
    player.y -= vy;
}
```

However, there are potential problems with this. First of all, `DisplayObject`/`x` and `y` round their values to "[twips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip)", so your addition and subtraction of `vx` and `vy` will not necessarily result in the object landing back in the original position exactly. This can produce problems with objects getting stuck in walls and such. Sound strange? Try this:

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.x = 1.1925;
trace(s.x); // 1.15
```

So, to avoid this, you can store the position separately instead of relying on the `DisplayObject` `x` and `y` property.

```
var oldPosition:Point = new Point(player.x, player.y);

player.x += vx;
if(player.hitTestObject(block)){
    player.x = oldPosition.x;
}

player.y += vy;
if(player.hitTestObject(block)){
    player.y = oldPosition.y;
}
```

Second, I thought I would just mention that while `hitTestObject()` is a convenient API to check the intersection of two display object bounding rectangles, in my experience when you mix it with movement and collision response it starts to break down, because it relies on the state of the display, which is subject to oddities like the twips rounding, and inflexible with timing (you can't, for example, project all your movements, then check collisions, since you need to move your display object to get a valid result from `hitTestObject()`). The better way IMO is to make collision detection purely math based, for example circle intersection/distance checks. All that `hitTestObject()` is really doing is [`Rectangle/intersects()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html#intersects%28%29) based on display objects bounds anyway. Pure math based collision detection is more work to setup, but more flexible and in my experience more predictable. Just a thought for the future, perhaps!

Comment: I get an error when using "Point". Do I need to import something?

Comment: Yes, you do. `import flash.geom.Point`. You don't need to use `Point`, I just find it a convenient container for x,y data. You could just as much use `oldX` and `oldY` number variables as well.

Comment: There is no need to undo the move. If player makes move and hits obstacle, its coordinate must be set just before the obstacle, so no error will happen ever. For example, `if (player.x + player.width > obstacle.x) player.x = obstacle.x - player.width`

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko It doesn't seem like you read the whole answer, or else my explanation didn't convey. There **is** a need to "undo" the move if using `hitTestObject()` as the OP is currently using. In the last paragraph I recommend changing to use a pure math based hit test, without going into detail because there are many ways it could be done. Your comment is *more* in that direction, but IMO makes too many assumptions to be helpful to the OP. (It is not coordinate space agnostic, assumes a specific display object orientation, and relies on display which I explained is not a good idea).

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko But please feel free to add your own answer if you feel you have a solution. ;)

Comment: Ok @Aaron, got you :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this question is very genuine - Just for the next time, make sure you clarify the *background* of your question (i.e I`m making a game with an actionscript 2d graphics, blah blah blah).

Anyhow, I'll copy you a part of a code i written back in the day when i was into developing javascript games. Since i dont know how your objects are arranged, i`ll modify it in a way that'll just introduce the general algorithm.

```
// player: a class that holds an array of moves, and other relevant information. Varys on your program.
var optimizePosition = function (player) {
    //after each time the player attempts to move, i check if he touches of the blocks. if he does, i move him back. 
   foreach(Block block in blocks)// replace this with an iterator for all the blocks
   {
   if (player.x-block.x < 32 ||  player.y-block.y < 32 ) // if player is touching a block:
        undoLastMove(getLastMove(player),player);

    }
     // a little extra: always good to check if he's going out of the screen in the same function:

    if(player.x > canvas.width - 64 || player.y > canvas.height - 64)
       undoLastMove(getLastMove(player),player);
}
```

and each time the player moves, i call the function:

`optimizePosition(player);`

The content of `undoLastMove(player)` will contain the code you written above.

Comment: I put a tag as actionscript 3.

Comment: @Crook Yes - yet, it'd be better if you'll give some general background in the problem description itself. This way, people can come up with more creative solutions than just a little fix here or there, and could help you in a more general level - And if they manage to understand a logical mistake which is beyond what you asked and their answer change the way you think, personally I think that's much better value then just the question itself. In the end, I guess i`m trying to say it won't hurt anyone, so why not? (:

Comment: I'm also confused on what undoLastMove(getLastMove(player),player);. If possible, can you explain a  general way of moving the player back when colliding? Thanks!

Comment: @Crook Inside the `var player{/*params*/}` you should store an integer that marks the last movement he had on the X / Y  Axis, and change it whenever the player moves. getLastMove is a possible (but not neccesary) function that returns an array where cell 0 is the X movement and cell 1 is the y movement. undoLastMove changes the cordinates of the player with those values. that's just one implementation which is fairly simple.